# How to run something just once after fetching Firestore collection?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following query:

```
firestore()
  .collection('users')
  .doc(userId)
  .onSnapshot(doc => setUser(doc.data()))
  .once(() => {
    // Do some things just once here!
  });
```

I need the `setUser` function to run each time the collection's data changes, so I set up a snapshot listener and it's working great.

But the `once` part isn't. I need the things inside that function to only be executed once (the first time the query is run and never again. Do I have the wrong method? Is there a built in method or some other way in Firestore to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a workflow supported by the SDK.  You'll just have to write some code to express this:

```
let first = true
firestore()
  .collection('users')
  .doc(userId)
  .onSnapshot(doc => {
    setUser(doc.data());
    if (first) {
      first = false;
      // Do some things just once here!
    }
  })
```

Comment: Bah, I was hoping to avoid setting flags but guess theres no built in way..

Comment: You can do either a single response with `get()` or listen with `onSnapshot()`, but not both combined into one.  You can always file feature request with Firebase support, but I haven't seen this come up for anyone at all since Firestore was launched.